# Partytown - GA4 bad data

Tags: google-analytics-4, partytown

we deployed **Partytown** on the [https://lekarna.cz](https://stackoverflow.com) website and our data in GA4 changed. Direct traffic increased from **10% to 30%** and engagement rate values ​​also changed. Can you think of where the problem might be?

We tried to go through the documentation and various forums but couldn't find anything